# pyBrain trainUntilConvergence... help me understand this function please

Tags: pybrain

I have several newbie questions about trainUntilConvergence in pyBrain.

trainUntilConvergence divides the data set into training and validation sets (defaults to 25% used for testing).  Is this correct?

Is the error reported (when verbose=True) after each epoch the error on the validation set or the error against the training set?

Is the network considered converged (thus stopping execution) when the validation set's error is no longer reducing?  Or when the error on the training set is no longer reducing? (I assume it's the former else why use a portion for validation?)

Is the section of data chosen for validation contiguous (e.g. the last x% of the data set) or does it choose x% of rows at random from the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://pybrain.org/docs/api/supervised/trainers.html) `trainUntilConvergence`, takes in several parameters. It's shown below. Yes it defaults to 25% used as the validation set.

```
trainUntilConvergence(dataset=None, maxEpochs=None, verbose=None, continueEpochs=10, validationProportion=0.25)
```

You can change the `validationProportion` parameters to other values as you see fit. The proportion of validation set is debatable and has no one-value-fits-all proportion. You need to try them to fit your case.

The `trainUntilConvergence`method trains on your data set until the error on the validation set is no longer decreasing for a certain number of epochs. You can vary the number of epochs that the trainer considers before stopping the training by changing the `continueEpochs` parameter. It defaults to 10. In other words, if the error on the validation set does not improve in 10 consecutive epochs, the training is terminated. This is also known as the `early stopping` method and its widely used in training neural nets.

Regarding the contiguous of the validation set i'm not sure about it. But logically it should select on random picks.